# DeleteMessageAsync() not deleting message in SQS queue .Net Core

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core-webapi, amazon-sqs

I am trying to delete message in SQS queue, but it is not deleting in the queue. I have been trying to make a lot of changes, but is still not working. I am new to c#, .net core, and AWS. Can anyone please help me with this?

Here is my main method:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ReceiveMessageResponse> Get()
    {
        

        ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest
        {
           WaitTimeSeconds = 3 //it'll ping the queue for 3 seconds if I don't do this, sometimes I receive message and sometimes I don't
        };

        receiveMessageRequest.QueueUrl = myQueueUrl;
        receiveMessageRequest.MaxNumberOfMessages = 10; // can change number of messages as needed

        //receiveing messages/responses
        var receiveMessageResponse = await amazonSQSClient.ReceiveMessageAsync(receiveMessageRequest);

        if (receiveMessageResponse.Messages.Count > 0){
            var bucketName = getBucketName(receiveMessageResponse);
            var objectKey = getObjectKey(receiveMessageResponse);
            var versionId = getVersionId(receiveMessageResponse);

            string filePath = "C:\\InputPdfFile\\"; // change it later

            string path = filePath + objectKey;               
            //get the file from s3 bucket and download it in in
            var downloadInputFile = await DownloadAsync(path, versionId, objectKey);

            //Get score from the output file
            string jsonOutputFileName = "\\file-1.txt"; //change it later from text file to json file
            string jsonOutputPath = "C:\\OutputJsonFile"; //change it later
           
            string jasonArchivePath = "C:\\ArchiveJsonFile"; //change it later
            int score = GetOutputScore(jsonOutputPath, jsonOutputFileName);

            //update metadata from the score received from ML worker (GetOutputScore)
            PutObjectResponse putObjectResponse = await UpdateMetadataAsync(score);

            //Move file from output to archive after updating metadata

            string sourceFile = jsonOutputPath + jsonOutputFileName;
            string destFile = jasonArchivePath + jsonOutputFileName;

            if (!Directory.Exists(jasonArchivePath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(jasonArchivePath);
            }

            System.IO.File.Move(sourceFile, destFile);

            //delete message after moving file from archive 
            *DeleteMessage(receiveMessageResponse);* //not sure why it is not deleting**
        }
        return receiveMessageResponse;

    }
```

Here is my Delete method:

```
public async void DeleteMessage(ReceiveMessageResponse receiveMessageResponse)
    {
        
        if (receiveMessageResponse.Messages.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var message in receiveMessageResponse.Messages)
            { 

                var delRequest = new DeleteMessageRequest
                {
                    QueueUrl = myQueueUrl,
                    ReceiptHandle = message.ReceiptHandle
                };
                var deleteMessage = await amazonSQSClient.DeleteMessageAsync(delRequest);    
                
            }
        }
        else // It is not going in else because the message was found but still not deleting it
        {
            
           Console.WriteLine("No message found");
        }
        
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you need to use  await keyword in your function call ```await DeleteMessage(receiveMessageResponse);```

Comment: I made these changes and also changed DeleteMessage(receiveMessageResponse) from void to Task because I was getting error. But it still doesn't delete anything :(